Can Frege's axiom of unrestricted comprehension be slightly modified to avoid the Russell paradox?
EDIT - The universal quantification of F should be at the far left, so the axiom I'm proposing is
PRINCIPLE OF RESTRICTED COMPREHENSION
∀F∃y [y is a set & ∀x[ not(F(x) ↔ x ∉ x ) → (x ∈ y ↔ F(x))]]

Russell showed that Frege's axiom 5, the principle of unrestricted comprehension is false, by considering the set of all and only sets that aren't elements of themselves.  It's my suspicion that that is the only paradoxical set.  So my question is, is the following principle of restricted comprehension true?  If it is, then you can prove the universal set U of all things subsists/exists.
PRINCIPLE OF RESTRICTED COMPREHENSION
∃y [y is a set & ∀F ∀x[ (F(x) ≠ x ∉ x ) → (x ∈ y ↔ F(x))]

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If your only purpose is to have a set theory with a universal set U, and you don't care if the sets are restricted in some way, then this has been done before, most notably in NF. However, Russel's Paradox is not the only problem you have to overcome so your solution won't work as is. Even more urgent than Russel's Paradox is something discovered by Cantor: the powerset of any set contains elements not in the set. So if you have a set U that contains all sets, then the set of all subsets of U contains sets not in U. This illustrates the essential problem with the notion of a completed universe of sets: that there is always a larger universe of sets. NF gets around the problem by restricting what is allowed as a set.

I'm fully aware that the power set supposedly contains more elements than in the set, but there's a loophole in the proof of that.  I will make a separate post on the loophole.  There can be a set of all things, that contains its power set.

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/112654/is-it-true-that-every-set-has-less-power-than-its-power-set

Cantor's Proof requires The Restricted Axiom of Comprehension, under this new axiom, Cantor's Proof wouldn't be possible.

Harder to dispense with is the problem that the Class of Ordinals is a Proper Class. Although, the OP seems to only allow properties defined by single variable propositional functions, so such objects may not appear in the theory they want to consider.

@David Gudeman, you said.   So if you have a set U that contains all sets, then the set of all subsets of U contains sets not in U. BUT IF U CONTAINS ALL SETS THEN ALL THE SUBSETS OF U, BEING SETS, ARE NECESSARILY ELEMENTS OF U.  So your inference is non sequitur

@leepappas, no, the conclusion is not a non sequitur because it follows from the premises. What it is is a contradiction, which is what you do when you are doing a proof by contradiction.

@leepappas David is totally right. The inference is a reductio ad absurdum: From "p → ¬p" you may derive "¬p".  I admire your persistence in trying to shoot holes in set theory etc, but my advise is to set your questions aside for a little while. But do keep notes to come back to them after you've studied the continuum hypothesis. And then still keep your questions in check, until you've thoroughly studied both Gödel's and Cohen's response. Then see if you still have questions or if your old questions have been resolved. I predict most will have been resolved by then.
