Is it true that every set has less elements than its power set?
Define Σ to be the set of all sets and only sets.  Consider the following proof that A < ℘(A), for any set A, found on page 97 of Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes.
The function f on A such that for X in A
f(x)={x}
Establishes that A has less than or equal power to A, since the set of unit sets of elements of A is a subset of the power set of A.
Now suppose A = ℘(A), under the function g, say domain g=A & range g = ℘(A).
Define:
B={y: y ∈A & y ∉ g(y)}
Hence on the basis of our supposition there must be an X in A such that g(x)=B.  But then we easily infer that
x ∈ g(x) iff x ∉ g(x)
which is absurd.  Hence we conclude our supposition is false. Now by the contrapositive of the Schroder-Bernstein theorem we conclude,
For any set A, A < ℘(A).
If you let A = Σ, it screws the whole proof up.
EDIT if you let A = U, where U is the set of all things, then you screw the whole proof up. Letting A = Σ does not create a problem in the way I thought, but it does also create a problem.  All elements of ℘(Σ) are elements of Σ so the power set of Σ doesn't have a greater power than Σ.
I'm not using ZF to conclude Σ subsists/exists.  I used the following axiom:
THE AXIOM OF RESTRICTED COMPREHENSION
∃ y[y is a set & ∀ F ∀x[F(x) ≠ x ∉ x → (x  ∈ y ↔ F(x))]
Simply let F be the predicate "is a set".  Then F(x)= x is a set.  Clearly NOT(F(x)= x ∉ x). Thus we can existentially instantiate the constant Σ for the variable y, to get:
Σ is a set & ∀x[x  ∈ Σ ↔ x is a set]
Therefore we conclude there subsists/exists a set such that if x is in that set then x is a set(so that set contains only sets), AND if x is a set then then x is in that set (so that set contains all sets).  Thus, the axiom of restricted comprehension allows us to conclude there is a set of all sets and only sets, which I have denoted by Σ.
The axiom of restricted comprehension is considerably more powerful than Zermelo's Aussonderung axiom, i.e the axiom of separation.  Couple the axiom of restricted comprehension with the axiom of Extensionality and you have the Axiomatic Set Theory I use.
AXIOM OF EXTENSIONALITY
∀ x[if x ∈ A ↔ x ∈ B then A = B]
EDIT The axiom of restricted comprehension should read
AXIOM OF RESTRICTED COMPREHENSION
∀ F ∃ y[y is a set & ∀ x [¬(F(x) iff x ∉ x ) → (x  ∈ y ↔ F(x))]]

Why does letting A=Σ screw anything up?

@David, since the power set of Sigma is Sigma, B is the set of y such that y is in Sigma and y isn't in sigma..  thus B is the empty set.  So you get: x in the empty set iff x in sigma and x not in Sigma, which isn't contradictory.

That's a circular argument.

B would be the set y is in sigma and y is not in g(y). We dont know that g(y) is Sigma.

@Michael, when he defined f(x)={x} he knew immediately all the outputs were elements of the power set of A.  Similarly when he defined g(y) he knew the outputs,i.e. the g(y)'s were elements of the power set of A.  Since the range of g(y) is the power set of A, g(y)=P(A).  So taking A=Sigma we have g(y)=P(Sigma)=Sigma.

How does the range(g) = P(A) imply that g(y) = P(A)?

@Michael, all the outputs are elements of the Range.  Since the range is P(A), for any x: g(x) iff x in P(A).  By the axiom of Extensionality g(y)=P(a), where y is an arbitrary element of A.

Im sorry, maybe it is a matter of notation or that I am used to an entirely different framework, but I really cannot follow your arguments. Thank you for your effort, but I don't believe I can help you with your question.

See Cantor's paradox in NF for the issue regarding set theories that have the "universal" set. Your argument above fails because you are trying to apply ZF to "he set of all sets and only sets", but this "object" does not exist in ZF.

@mauro-im not working in ZF.https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/112635/can-freges-axiom-of-unrestricted-comprehension-be-slightly-modified-to-avoid-th#comment345022_112635 I'm using the axiom of restricted comprehension+Extensionality.

This argument relies on using a non-standard set theory. Until the question is updated to explain this, I recommend closing it as "needs more details".

"Since the range of g(y) is the power set of A, g(y)=P(A)." Im dont understand this. isn't it just range g = P(A)? g(y) is simply ∈ P(A)

"Define Σ to be the set of all sets..."
The supposition that such a set exists leads almost inevitably to contradictions, so most, if not all, versions of modern set theory don't allow you to define one. There are different ways to prevent you from doing so, but the bog-standard basic one is called "limited/bounded comprehension".
You can check out the Wikipedia page on Russell's Paradox  to start learning more, if you're curious.

Show you one what? A contradiction? Go read the Wikipedia article on Russell's Paradox.

There must be errors in those supposed proofs that Sigma leads to a contradiction.  There's nothing wrong with saying x is a set iff x is an element of Sigma.  Show me any supposed contradiction, and I'll find an error in the proof.

Go read Russell's Paradox.

Russell's set isn't the set of all sets and only sets, it's the set of all sets and only sets that aren't elements of themselves.

So you want to give up constructing new sets by comprehension? Russell's set isn't your "universal set", but it is a subset of your set, constructed via comprehension. And you used comprehension to construct your set B, so I have no idea what version of set theory you're using.

I am using an Axiomatic Set Theory with the axiom of restricted comprehension.https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/112635/can-freges-axiom-of-unrestricted-comprehension-be-slightly-modified-to-avoid-th#comment344969_112635. The Russell set cannot be constructed using my axiom of restricted comprehension

@leepappas If sigma is a set that contains all sets, does it contain itself?

Yes, it contains itself.  Similarly, the universal set U of all things contains itself.  Neither of these sets contain ONLY sets that don't contain themselves.  So no paradox.
